# Delete lines in a file that start with specific strings

Tags: sed

I have some files that look like this:

```
Node   Present
1   243
2   445
10  65
4  456
43  8
...
```

I need to remove the values corresponding to specific nodes and I have a file specifying this nodes that looks like this:

```
1
4
...
```

The idea is to delete the lines that start with the values specified in my second file. I know that "sed" can do something like this, but I do not know how to apply it for all the values specified in the second file. More over, I want to delete node 1, but not node 100, and I am seeing that node 100 will also get erased with my approach.

```
sed '/^1/d'
```

Comment: Don't use sed.  With awk, read the file that specifies the node to skip and then go through the input file not printing lines that were specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is not the right tool for this job. I suggest using `awk` like this:

```bash
awk 'NR == FNR {ids[$1]; next} NR == 1 || !($1 in ids)' ids nodes

Node   Present
2   445
10  65
43  8
```

Where input files are:

```bash
cat ids
1
4

cat nodes
Node   Present
1   243
2   445
10  65
4  456
43  8
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have never used awk. Can I speify full paths to my files (in case they are in different directories)? Does awk delete the specified rows in the file or it just prints it to the terminal?

Comment: Yes you can provide path of the files to awk. gnu-awk has inline saving option but older awk versions didn't have it.  Just use `awk '...' ids nodes > output && mv output nodes` for POSIX awk

Comment: If you have gnu-wk then just use: `awk -i inplace 'NR == FNR {ids[$1]; next} NR == 1 || !($1 in ids)' ids nodes`

Answer (score 3):

This sort of problem is typically done with `awk`, and is quite common.  Read the first file into an array, and then use it to process subsequent files.  For example:

```
$ cat skip 
1
4
$ cat input
Node   Present
1   243
2   445
10  65
4  456
43  8
...
$ cat input2
Node   Present
1   243
2   445
4  456
43  8
4 587
...
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1] = 1; next} ! a[$1] && FNR > 1' skip input input2
2   445
10  65
43  8
...
2   445
43  8
...
```

The initial `NR == FNR` causes those command to only be executed on the first file, loading the array with the ids you wish to skip.  Subsequent commands print lines in which the first column did not appear in the first file and the first line of each file, in which FNR > 1. (FNR is the "File Record Number", aka the line number in the file.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `sed` and `bash`, here is one possible way how you would do it. Please note that, for large files, that would take orders of magnitude longer to run than the `awk` answers (similar to time complexity of linear search vs binary search).

```
sed -f <(sed 's/^/\/^/;s/[[:blank:]]*$/[[:blank:]]\/d/' ids) nodes
```

`ids` is filename of single-column file and `nodes` is that of two-column.